# Linq Contains check on string had mis-detect

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use **LINQ** to filter data from a string via **LINQ**, my *expected result* was only `1, 4, 15`. but the sample show only `1, 4`. it can't distinguish between `5` and `15`.

could anyone give me some advice, thank you.

Here is [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kqjbDc)

```
        string sa = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15";
        string sr = "2, 3, 5";

        var r1 = sa.Where(l => !sr.Contains(l));
        var r2 = sa.Except(sr);

        var r3 = string.Join(",", sa.Except(sr));

        foreach (var i in r1)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var j in r2)
        {
            Console.Write(j + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(r3);
```

The results show:

```
1, 4, 1, 
1, 4, 
1,4
```

Comment: Why don't you work on a list of int ? you can simply convert it to a list of int. because for string 15 contains 5

Comment: and if you want to start by converting your string representation of a List int first , you can use Something like : `Func<string, int?> myTryParse = s => int.TryParse(s, out int n) ? (int?)n : null;` and filter the null out if some of the value are not int^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for `Split`?

```
var r3 => string.Join(", " sa
  .Split(new string[] { ", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Except(sr.Split(new string[] { ", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)));
```

We *split* each string into items:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15" -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15  
"2, 3, 5"           -> 2, 3, 5
```

then perform `Except`:

```
Except:                1, 4, 15
```

Finally, `Join` the string back from the items:

```
1, 4, 15            -> "1, 4, 15"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you operate LINQ queries over a `string`, you are using it as an array, and are operating over the characters.

So, the LINQ queries never see `15` ever. They only see the character `5` and the character `1`

Changing from strings, to int arrays, will allow you to pass the numbers to LINQ

The **only** change was where the numbers were defined.

```
string sa = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15";
string sr = "2, 3, 5";
```

became

```
int[] sa = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15};
int[] sr = {2, 3, 5};
```

Which changed the type of elements that LINQ was working over, from characters to ints.

Before you were also operating on the whitespace, and the comma's which you probably didn't want to do.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kqjbDc

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] sa = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15};
        int[] sr = {2, 3, 5};

        var r1 = sa.Where(l => !sr.Contains(l));
        var r2 = sa.Except(sr);

        var r3 = string.Join(",", sa.Except(sr));

        foreach (var i in r1)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var j in r2)
        {
            Console.Write(j + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(r3);

    }
}
```

result

```
1, 4, 15, 
1, 4, 15, 
1,4,15
```

Answer (score 1):

There is your Problem

```
 var r1 = sa.Where(l => !sr.Contains(l));
```

15 did contains the 5 so he cant select the 15.

use following Code to check for the complete number:

```
var r1 = sa.Where(l => sr.Any(f => f != l));
```